# Prove the existence of a continuous random variable given a cumulative distribution function

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, density-function

I'm taking a course in probability and statistics and I was given the following problem: Let $F:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1] $ be a continuous, strictly increasing function that satisfies $\lim_{x\to \infty}{F(x)}=1 \ \land \ \lim_{x\to-\infty}{F(x)}=0$. Prove that there exists a random variable $X$ that has F as a cumulative distribution function.

So, I can see that F satisfies all the conditions to be a CDF, but I can't assume that it's a differentiable function(which would allow me to define a probability density function). And if I can't prove the existence of a probability density function, then I can't prove the existence of a continuous random variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question wants you to take a uniform variable $U \in (0,1)$ and map it to a random variable $X = h(U)$ (for some function $h$) so that $P[X\leq x] = F(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  This is also how you can generate a random variable with a given distribution (starting with a uniformly distributed variable).

Comment: @Michael I see, I think I was able to solve it by taking $g=F^{-1}$. I know that $F$ has an inverse because it's continuous and strictly increasing. So, $P(X\leq t)=P(F^{-1}(U)\leq t)=P(U\leq F(t))=F(t)$ and I know that $F(t)\in (0,1)$ because of the information I was given about $F$. Did I get it right?